# Adavancedquery in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on Elastic Search for my current Project. I am working Keyword Word Based functionality. And My Query as follows

```
$query = array("from" => 0,
            "size" => 20,
            "query" => array(
                "filtered" => array(
                    "query" => array("match" => array('_all' => trim(strtolower($keyword))))
        )));
        $result = $this->elasticsearch->advancedquery("services", json_encode($query));
```

if user enters his keyword it comes to $keyword and search "services" type. this functionality working fine. but I want search that keyword in multiple types. i.e. 
In My Index.. I am having two types "products" and "services". 
I need to search my keyword in both types.

Answer (score 0):

use multi_match

```
 {"query" : {"multi_match" : {"query": $keyword,"fields": [ "products", "services" ]}}}
```

Comment: Hi @Alainlb, in the above question i used "advancedquery". for type services. is there any alternate query (like advancedquery) for multi_match.

Comment: sorry i don't know, i don't use your elasticsearch angular librairie. the query don't work ?

Comment: yeah, but my problem was solved. I have taken individually..  by using "advancedquery" only i.e.
$this->elasticsearch->advancedquery("services", json_encode($query));
$this->elasticsearch->advancedquery("products", json_encode($query)); and finally i have merged total result into one array.